# My C program keeps running without appearing any output

Tags: c, gcc, path, console-application, mingw

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int leNumeroInteiro();
void leDadosRetangulo(int *comp, int *larg);
void areaRetangulo(int comp, int larg);
void limparBufferStdin();

int main() {
    int comp, larg;
    leDadosRetangulo(&comp, &larg);
    areaRetangulo(comp, larg);
    return 0;
}

void limparBufferStdin() {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

int leNumeroInteiro() {
    int num;
    do {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        limparBufferStdin();
        
    } while (!(num > 0));

    return num;
}

void leDadosRetangulo(int *comp, int *larg) {
    printf("=====================\n");
    printf("\nIntroduza o comprimento do retangulo: ");
    *comp = leNumeroInteiro(); 
    printf("\nIntroduza a largura do retangulo: ");
    *larg = leNumeroInteiro(); 
    printf("=====================\n");
}

void areaRetangulo(int comp, int larg) {
    float area;
    area = (float)comp * larg;
    printf("=====================\n");
    printf("A area desse retangulo e: %.2f\n", area);
}
```

It keeps running the code until I cancel.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoXv3.png)

I confirmed I had the version correctly installed. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6swnD.png)

I selected the correct path [even in enviromental variables] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3D3r.png)

When I run a simple code with just a printf, it works perfectly, but with my code it doesn't appear anything. I tried running it in Codeblocks (other IDE) and it ran perfectly. I tried reinstalling Mingw a lot of times, I saw a lot of tutorials. I'm getting desperate.

Comment: You mention that this works when utilizing Codeblocks (which, actually is the IDE I mainly use).  What IDE are you trying to execute this in?  Possibly it's some type of IDE project setup issue.  FYI, when I actually entered in the concatenated command in the standard Windows command prompt, everything worked as well.

Comment: I was changing my IDE from codeblocks to VSCODE. I'm relatively new to programming in C, so I'm not used to setting up VSCODE for C. I know the code is not the problem, it could have been some loop that runs forever, but that's not the issue either.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the program within 'Terminal'?
I suspect you aren't. I ran your program and it works perfectly for me. So I think you are just in the wrong section of the IDE.

Comment: No, it should be output because the terminal is for debbuging the C program. I have other C file with just a printf that shows the output. I think this might be some problem with MinGW or a condiguration. I can't find anything to solve it, i've tried almost everything.